# Error while writing socket code for creating quiz

Tags: mysql, reactjs, database, websocket, socket.io

```
 code: 'ER_NO_REFERENCED_ROW_2',
```

errno: 1452,
sqlMessage: 'Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`databasename`.`quizzes_player_1_id_links`, CONSTRAINT `quizzes_player_1_id_links_inv_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `up_users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)',
sqlState: '23000',
index: 0,
sql: 'insert into `quizzes_player_1_id_links` (`quiz_id`, `user_id`) values (1, 1)'

Can anyone tell me what is the error about? How to fix this?

Comment: There's not entry in `up_users` with id `1`.

Answer (score 0):

The good answer is ...

You have to check if all values in column 'user_id' exist in the column 'id'.

You should have a problem on this point .... It was the problem on my side.